# call function when filereader.onload has finished reading the files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
submitTCtoDB(updateTagForm:any){
    for(let i=0;i<this.selectedFileList.length;i++){

  let file=this.selectedFileList[i];
  this.readFile(file, function(selectedFileList) {
      this.submitTC(updateTagForm,selectedFileList);
});

     }

    }

  }

readFile(file, callback){
    let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload= () => {
    this.fileContent=fileReader.result;
    if(this.fileContent.indexOf("END DATA | BEGIN RESULTS") != -1){

    alert("Multiple testcases found in "+file.name+" file.  Please separate/save testcases in Calc Builder. Then reimport");

    const index: number = this.selectedFileList.indexOf(file);

    if (index > -1) {
     this.selectedFileList.splice(index, 1);
     console.log(file.name+"removed from the list");
 }  



}
    fileReader.readAsText(file);

  }
  callback(this.selectedFileList);
  }

submitTC(updateTagForm:any,selectedFileList){
    //process the selectedFileList came after the readFile has finished erading the files
  }
```

i want to execute the submitTC function after the fileReader has finished reading the files..not sure if readFile() callback is implemented correctly.Please help writing this logic.
Flow> When user clicks submitTCtoDB is called and then readFile should work and read the files and return the selectedFileList after splicing the unwanted elements from it..then submitTC will take that list and proceed further.

Please help.

Comment: when reading file you can get an error. you can take a look at **onloadEnd** event for handle both success and error or you can handle error in **onerror** event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0):

You should use es6 arrow function `=>` instead of `function` declarations to get the instance of the current class method.

```
submitTCtoDB(updateTagForm:any){
  for(let i=0;i<this.selectedFileList.length;i++){

    let file=this.selectedFileList[i];
    this.readFile(file, (selectedFileList) => {
        this.submitTC(updateTagForm,selectedFileList);
     });

   }

 }
```

To know whether the file reading is completed or not you can use `FileReader.result` property. It is `null` until the file reading completed it's process.

According to mozilla docs

> An appropiate string or ArrayBuffer based on which of the reading methods was used to initiate the read operation. The value is null if the reading is not yet complete or was unsuccessful.

Comment: ---the approach of callback is correct?I am new to javascript callbacks..

Comment: I have updated my answer on how to know the file reading is finished

Comment: bearnithi@gmail.com